# Greatest lower bound and meet-semilattice of set

Tags: lattice-orders

I am wondering if I am understanding this concept correctly.

A partially ordered set $S$ is called a meet-semilattice if, for all $x,y \in S$, a unique greatest lower bound of $x$ and $y$ exists.

So let's say we have the set $S = \{1,2,3,12,36\}$, and we want to ask if this set, when partially ordered by divisibility, is a meet-semilattice.

I am inclined to say that NO it is not. If we take $x = 12$ and $y=36$, then there are three lower bounds ($1,2,3$). But, none of them is the greatest since $2$ and $3$ do not divide each other.

Is my logic/approach correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $\{12,36\}$ actually has $4$ lower bounds; the one you missed is $12$, which also happens to be the **greatest** lower bound. In general, if $x$ and $y$ are comparable, they automatically have a greatest lower bound (and a least upper bound). You only need to check incomparable pairs, in this case, $\{2,3\}$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Completely went over my head to include the 12 as well. So this would then be a "meet-semilattice" correct? Any tips on how I would draw this lattice structure?

Comment: Yes, it's a meet-semilattice, and a join-semilattice too, so it's a lattice. I don't know how to post pictures. Draw a diamond with $1$ at the bottom, $2$ and $3$ on the sides, $12$ at the top; $36$ above the $12$ and a vertical line connecting $12$ to $36$.